# archive failed with validation error and code "dyld: Symbol not found: _OBJC_CLASS_$_DVTITunesConnectProxy"

Tags: xcode6, archive

I was trying to archive my app and do testFlight afterwards. But every time when I tried to archive, this same error message would show up.

I have generated provisioning file and I have added certificate. One thing is that when I clicked on my provisioning file for distribution, Xcode would pop up, and there is no iPhone configuration utility anymore.

Could anyone help me that what I have done wrong or what is missing?

```
 dyld: Symbol not found: _OBJC_CLASS_$_DVTITunesConnectProxy
  Referenced from: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/Validation
  Expected in: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/../../../../../../SharedFrameworks/DVTFoundation.framework/Versions/A/DVTFoundation
 in /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/Validation
Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/Validation failed with exit code 5
```

Comment: I did succeed by following this webpage: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1814/_index.html. I guess it is mainly because the setting of the "code signing" that I should set to "Don't code sign" and "automatic"! So detailed mistake!!

Comment: Same error happening again!!! It didn't solve this time...